# How to print only the capture groups of all matches in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

How to print only the capture groups of all matches in perl? `/g` doesn't seem to work.

*I don't think I'm doing any of it correctly, using `if` statements, this is why am asking. How is the proper way to do it?* (I can't find anything on the Internet that helps and I am struggling for hours to make it finally work.)

```perl
$LONG_REGEX_WITH_TWO_CAPTURING_GROUPS="";
$file1="file1.html";

/* This part is complicated, this is why I said nothing 
 * about the two, but here is the result:
 *
 * Basically $2 (a letter) + whitespace + $1 (a filename)
 * a file.txt
 * b anotherfile.txt
 * c 3rdfile.txt
 * d 4thfile.txt
 * 
 * I want it to become>
 * a - (A specific part of the text in file.txt)
 * b - (A specific part of the text in anotherfile.txt)
 * etc.
*/

my $content1 = do { open my $fh, '<', $file1 or die $!; local $/; <$fh>; };

if ( $content1 =~ /$LONG_REGEX_WITH_TWO_CAPTURING_GROUPS/g ) {
    # Print the letter first ($2).
    print "$2 - ";
    # Open the corresponding file (it's name is $1).
    my $content2 = do { open my $fh, '<', $1 or die $!; local $/; <$fh>; };
    # Try to complete the task.
    if ( $content2 =~ /$SECOND_REGEX/g ) {
        print "$1\n"; # There is just one capturing group.
    }
}
```

However, this only prints the first match, even if it has a global flag.

As in:

`a - The desired text.`

Nevermind the code, the question is very simple: How to print only the content from the capture groups, but from all of the matches (or making it so it matches everything in the file)?

Thank you!

**I'm editing so I can put the code here:**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$file1="file1.html";
my $content1 = do { open my $fh, '<', $file1 or die $!; local $/; <$fh>; };

foreach ( $content1 =~ m/LONG_REGEX_WITH_TWO_CAPTURING_GROUPS/g ) {
    # If I were to put a print "$content1"; here, the program would have
    # no output. Here is the problem, the question still remains.
    print "$2 - ";
    my $content2 = do { open my $fh, '<', $1 or die $!; local $/; <$fh>; };
    foreach ( $content2 =~ m/SECOND_REGEX>/g ) {
        print "$1\n"; # There is just one capturing group.
    }
}
```

**This worked for me:**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$file1="file1.html";
my $content1 = do { open my $fh, '<', $file1 or die $!; local $/; <$fh>; };
while ( $content1 =~ /LONG_REGEX_WITH_TWO_CAPTURING_GROUPS/g ) 
    print "$2 - ";
    my $content2 = do { open my $fh, '<', "../../VT/$1" or die $!; local $/; <$fh>; };
    while ( $content2 =~ /SECOND_REGEX/g ) {
        print "$1\n\n<br/>"; # There is just one capturing group.
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean, this works ```perl -0777 -ne 'while(m/LONG_REGEX_WITH_TWO_CAPTURING_GROUPS/g";}'``` but I have two files and I need more code to obtain the desired result.

Comment: I recommend adding a line `my ($filename, $letter) = ($1,$2);` immediately after the successful match. This saves you from accidental bugs when you add code that modifies `$1` and `$2`.  Save off those two values before you do anything else to make sure they don't get spoiled.  Of course, it will also be clearer when you `open $fh, '<', $filename`, too.

Comment: @doqx  Can you show a sample (string) for what you are matching? It would shrink the number of possibilities here :)  (see my answer -- there can be a number of ways to do this)

Answer (score 3):

You want to iterate over the matches, but you have no loop. The g modifier makes you an array of all matches and you have to iterate over the array.

```
@matches = ( 'foo' =~ m{o}g );
```

This would make you an array with two `"o"` strings in it.

You can iterate over the matches with code like this:

```
foreach ( 'foo' =~ m{o}g ) { ... }
```

If You want to iterate and need only the matching group, you must call the matching operator in scalar context. Here is an example how to do it:

```
$str="a m7 bcd 9 m2 cde m3";
while ($str =~ m{m(\d)}g) {
   print "$1\n";
}
```

This prints 7, 2 and 3, each in a line.

Comment: But how to make the array contain only the capture groups, not the full match, not what is in between them?

Comment: I've updated my question to paste the code there, it still doesn't work, can you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear to me how exactly that regex is meant to work but here are two possible situations.

It seems that you have a regex that matches multiple (two) subpatterns within one large pattern. Then you don't need the `/g` modifier; when the large pattern matches the subpatterns are matched as well (capture as needed). Then you can have the [`m` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#m%2FPATTERN%2Fmsixpodualngc) in list context so that it returns these captures, instead of returning true/false, what it does in the scalar context

```
my $string = q(73 name);

my @matches = $string =~ /([0-9]+) \s* ([a-z]+)/xi;

if (@matches) {
    # it matched, process the two captures
}
```

This can be done inside the condition of the `if` statement

```
if (my @matches = $string =~ /([0-9]+)\s*([a-z]+)/i) { 
    # getting here only means that there were *some* matches
    # check @matches as suitable, process
}
```

Now this whole thing is scoped to the `if` statement; there is no `@matches` variable outside.

Or, in this case you can simply use the capture variables, like

```
if ( $string =~ /([0-9]+) \s* ([a-z]+)/xi ) {
    # use $1 and $2 (check whether they were both defined)
}
```

See more on [regex operators in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), and look over the reference [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre).

---

Another possibility is that a regex pattern need be matched multiple times in the string, as the engine goes along the string and parses it. For that you indeed need the `\g` modifier.

It says in ["Global matching" in perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Global-matching)

> [...] The modifier `/g` stands for global matching and allows the matching operator to match within a string as many times as possible. In scalar context, successive invocations against a string will have `/g` jump from match to match, keeping track of position in the string as it goes along. [...]

Since you need both matches at the same time for processing you need to match in the [list context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Context) and capture the returned matches into an array, then process that array.  For example

```
my $string = '1 one 2 two';
my @matches = $string =~ /([a-z]+)/gi;  # @matches has elements: ('one', 'two')
# check how many @matches, etc
```

or perhaps have it inside `if` like above

```
if (my @matches = $string =~ /([a-z]+/gi) { 
    # check, process...
}
```

Add suitable checks for what was caught in `@matches` before processing it.

---

*Comments on the code posted in Q*

When you have the regex as the condition for an `if` statement it is in the "scalar" context.  This means, as the quote from the docs above shows, that it will return matches one by one -- if invoked repeatedly.  In your `if` it runs once, so you only get the first match.  So `$2` is `undef`.

When you have it under `foreach` (in the Edit), then it *is* indeed in the list condition -- but `foreach` obtains a list from the statement (so both matches) and then it *iterates* through it.  So every time through you only have *one* of the matches on hand! Again no good.